# Store SMS body as string in Python with Twilio

Tags: python, sms, twilio

I'd like to get the body of an SMS message sent to my Twilio number saved as a string in my python program. I can't find any documentation on how to do this. I have a program that lets me know when a new message is sent, but I don't know how to access it.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from TwilioPasswords import *
import time

while True:
    client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
    messages = client.messages.list()
    print(len(messages))
    time.sleep(5)
```

So every 5 seconds, it lets me know how many messages I have. In `messages` I get a list of data like `<twilio.rest.resources.messages.Message object at 0x03462DB0>`. I want to get the body of that message. How can I do this?

Comment: Try `help(messages[0])` to see what kinds of attributes the `Messages` object has. One of them will probably be the body, or there might be a method to get the body.

Comment: @kindall I see a line that says attribute:: body, but I don't know how to use it. I'm a bit new to python. I uploaded the full output here: http://pastebin.com/ExyVRjHi

Comment: For the record, the `.` is how you access attributes of objects (as seen in `client.messages.list()`). So as gipsy has shown, you iterate over the messages using a `for` loop, and then get each message's `body` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for message in messages:
  print message.body
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I notice you're polling the Twilio API once every 5 seconds in order to retrieve new messages. While that does work, there is a better way to receive messages from Twilio.

Instead of polling, you can setup a URL that Twilio will send an HTTP request to, known as a webhook, every time you get a new message sent to your Twilio number. You can then extract the body of the message from the parameters of that request.

There is a great guide on [how to receive SMS messages using Python and Flask](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/sms/how-to-receive-and-reply-in-python) which I recommend you take a read through.